# Regex negative lookbehind replace in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, negative-lookbehind

I have a JS regex with a negative lookbehind assertion that works fine in Chromium-based browsers:

```
(?<!https?:)\/\/(.+?)(?<!https?:)\/\/gmi
```

I need to replace it to another for cross browser compatibility (won't work in FF or Safari).

Regex means "Find and capture all occurrence
 inside slashes // //, except if before // stay http: or https:".

Example:

```
bar //foo bar// foo - match (capture //foo bar//)
//https://stackoverflow.com/// - match (capture https://stackoverflow.com/)
https://stackoverflow.com// - not match
//foo http://stackoverflow.com - not match
```

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mU5rR8/18)

As @BaliBalo said, my current regex contains error and work not perfectly
[Error Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mU5rR8/19)
I need capture `https://stackoverflow.com/` in `//https://stackoverflow.com///`

Comment: The second line would capture `https://stackoverflow.com` without the trailing slach, right?

Comment: @BaliBalo no, with trailing slash (like in example, need capture https://stackoverflow.com/ )

Comment: @JohnDoe your current regex with lookbehinds doesn't: https://regex101.com/r/mU5rR8/19

Comment: @sln it's possible,cause i saw example,that work. But,unfortunately,code was obfuscated

Comment: @BaliBalo so,my regex contains error...thanks for attentiveness!

Comment: @sln it can be done with temporary cut links to exclude interceptions,incorrect captures and simplifications regex,but it highly unwanted.

Comment: agree with @sln!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use them in a replace, you can try the opposite. Also capture what you don't want if it's there, and if that's the case just ignore the match. This behaves slightly differently in some edge cases but is acceptable in most situations.

Your regex could for example be:

```
let result = input.replace(/(https?:)?\/\/((?:https?:\/\/|.)+?)\/\//g, (m, e1, val) => e1 ? m : '[match](' + val + ')');
```